# reflecting nested property literals in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript/JavaScript and am trying to figure out a few things. I've got a type defined like such:

```
declare module "Names" {
 export = Names;
  const Names: {
   readonly name1: string;
   readonly name2: string;
   readonly name3: {
    readonly name3SubName1: string;
...
```

I'm trying to extract the names and values of all the strings from the Names object at runtime and Names can have nesting to multiple depth levels.

I've been able to get the "top level" properties by iterating through the results of

```
Object.keys(Names)
```

but since the return value from that call is strings I'm not able to go in any deeper. In this example I would like to get into name3.name3SubName1. I've also tried combinations of hasOwnProperty and getOwnProperty, but am not able to get any of the nested properties. Is there a common practice for "reflecting" property objects in TS objects that can deal with nesting?

Comment: I believe you're confusing declaration with definition but regardless, if you define something to be a string it will be a string. You don't need to do anything special here.

Comment: Maybe not clear; given Names (or any object for that matter) and passing that to Object.keys(Names) I get back an array of strings; in this case the values: 'name1', 'name2', and 'name3', but not 'name3SubName1'. In this case I might like something more like an array of "Properties" so that I could examine each one to see if they contain any children;

Comment: that's the way `Object.keys` behaves. It always returns an array of strings. You might want `Object.values` or `Object.entries`. However, if you want to retrieve nested property names to arbitrary depths you will want to use recursion

Comment: Object.entries does indeed do what I want, but my environment seems to be es5, looks like I get to learn about polyfills next :-). Thanks Aluan!

Comment: Sure. You can always grab `core-js` to get a massive amount of polyfills but it is a fairly large dependency.